# How to power and animate origami soldiers?

Tags: technology, warfare, robots, power-sources

Set in near future, a sheet of metal can fold itself into a soldier with the height of a full grown men and can pick up ranged weapon. This is inspired by the folding of solar sail technology of artificial satellite but how can it move as it weights a ton on Earth's surface? The idea is to airdrop millions of these origami soldiers into enemy territory and let them loose on a killing spree for a short period of time which is usually sufficient to turn the tide of war, I think nanotechnology can let them communicate with each other and coordinate their attacks and maybe grant them ability to self heal but would be far fetched for mobility on the ground.

Comment: Personally, I think the idea is too far fetched to bother having a realistic scientific solution, as more relevant questions would have to be handwaved before hand. If the technology to do such already exists then the need to create origami soldiers seems superfluous. There are far more capable shapes to conform to than people, and smart-metal capable of all those actions should be capable of far more than that far more easily. That is unless it is a sort of science-magic hybrid in which case all of that could make perfect sense depending on what rules are set for your magic system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get fancy and use a [radioisotope thermal generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) based on Polonium-210: with a power density of 140 W/g and an half-life of 0.378 years, it ensures that you can get enough power to supply the ton beast and also that it doesn't stay powered for too long in case things go wrong.

With a few kg of Polonium you get enough juice to power the device without overloading it.

Answer (score 3):

Since we're talking near (or not so near) future, what about an [atomic isomer battery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_gamma_emission)?  Metastable-2 Hafnium 178 can store 1330 MJ of energy per gram, and it has a half-life of 31 years.  It is believed that Hf-178m2 can be made to release its stored energy by induced gamma emission.

This ability to store great amounts of energy in room-temperature atoms would be ideal for powering such a compact device.

Answer (score 1):

**They are not that heavy.**

[image: gold foil]

https://physicsopenlab.org/2016/11/06/gold-leaf-thickness-with-alpha-spectrum/

Your origami soldiers move by virtue of bimetallic strips.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimetallic_strip

[image: bimetallic strips]

The AI on their chest is the size of a wristwatch.  Multiple coin size batteries are distributed about the creation.

As I envision your gleaming soldiers, they would weigh about 30 kg each.  Even I could take one out with a garden spade and one good hit (though don't turn your back on that one...)  But I do not get close enough to do that more than once because they have ranged weapons and they will shoot me.

As regards ranged weapons against these metal origami soldiers, they do not work well at all.  The gold is quite reflective against energy weapons.  Projectiles go through and keep going, leaving a hole behind.  Some of the soldiers have multiple patches from previous mishaps.

A weighted fishing net thrown from a roof would work well in a pinch.  This anime is unfolding before my eyes!  So to speak.

---

I think metal origami soldiers are an awesome idea and an excellent spin on robot soldiers.  There were origami attackers in Spirited Away but just paper ones.  This concept has a steampunky feel perfect for a world like that of Arcane.